# Использование QDoubleValidator для контроля ввода и вывода строки

Tags: c++, qt, валидация

Доброго времени суток!
Реализую калькулятор на Qt. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Использовал `QString::number(a1, 'f', 10)` для вывода не в экспоненциальной форме, но в итоге получаю лишние нули в конце. Можно ли использовать `QDoubleValidator` чтоб избавиться от нулей?
2. Нужен контроль ввода запятой в числе (можно ввести только одну запятую). Я думаю это можно реализовать так:

   ```
   QString str;
   int i;
   QLineEdit *Result = new QLineEdit(this);
   if (Result->validator()->validate(str,i)==QValidator::Invalid) return;
   ```

   Может есть способ получше или это вообще не правильно?

Спасибо за помощь и потраченное время.

Comment: А после `QString::number(a1, 'f', 10)` у вас строка с точкой или запятой получается?

Comment: @cassini с запятой строка

Answer (score 1):

Возможно `QDoubleValidator` тут не пригодится.

1. Отсекать хвостовые нули при формировании `QString` из `double` можно следующим образом:

   ```
   QString str = QString::number(a1, 'f', 10);
   str.remove(QRegExp(",?0+$"));
   ```

   Если после запятой ничего не остается, то отсекется и она.
2. Для контроля ввода можно использовать `QRegExpValidator`:

   ```
   QRegExpValidator *v = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^\\d+|\\d+,\\d+$"));
   lineEdit->setValidator(v);
   ```

   В такой форме он не позволит ввести более одной запятой и ввести запятую как первый символ, но позволяет оставить запятую вконце. Вызов `validate()` у этого валидатора на строку с запятой вконце вернет `QValidator::Intermediate`.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `QDoubleValidator` здесь вполне можно, так как ему можно давать свои шаблоны, с количеством нулей в конце - [Дока по QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html#setRange)

Comment: а такое не поможет?
`doubleValidator->setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);`

Comment: @ДекстерМорган да, я проверил, может помочь. В любом случае попробуйте.

Comment: не покажите как проверили? у меня вот такой вывод строки `ui->display->setText(text + digit);`

Comment: Ответ выше по-сути то, что я предлагал до того как исправил этот ответ.